# Problem installing rivet nuts

Tags: tools, fastener

I'm trying to install aluminum rivet nuts for some 8-32 hex screws.  I don't have the special tool so I'm trying to do it with a nut and 2 wrenches.  The problem I'm having is that the screws keep keeps sheering off at the nut (they're stainless but I don't know what their rating is). Does this mean that a #8 screw can't handle the tension needed to collapse the rivet?  Is there anything else I can do (besides splurging on the proper tool)?

Comment: There's an old saying: Right tool for the right job. If you're going to use the rivet nut, get the tool to make it work right.

Comment: Sometimes the place you need to work in is too small for the correct tool  and you need a work-around...

Comment: It's also hard to justify the cost of an expensive tool for a small, one-time job.

Comment: how exactly are you doing this? You should not be torquing the screw once its threaded in place (straight pull, not turned).  Why are you using a stainless screw?

Answer (score 3):

Change the stainless screw for a hardened one of the same size. If that fails then you'll be splurging...